How does EVM chains update the states of Predeploys?
I was checking one of the predeploys contract on BASE, which is the L1BlockNumber contract at https://basescan.org/address/0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000013#readProxyContract
This contract has a method called getL1BlockNumber and the value is changed constantly, and it is up to date compared with current Ethereum latest block height.
However, I didn't see any incoming transaction changing this state.
How does BASE or other EVM chains achieve this without sending any transactions?
Thanks!

The block information from L1 is not actually stored in this contract. It comes from the L1Block contract. As shown below, the L1BlockNumber contract calls the L1Block contract. The Predeploys.L1_BLOCK_ATTRIBUTES is simply the address of the L1Block contract.

In the L1Block contract, you can see all the transactions updating the latest block info.
